# intelliji doesn't make jar (artefact)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

here is what I've done exactly :

> File -> Project Structure -> Artefacts -> "+" -> Jar -> "From modules
>   with dependencies"  -> "All Modules" -> Checked : "Extracted to the
>   target JAR" -> click on (the little folder icon) -> the tab :
>   "Projects" -> src-> Zerko (is the main file) -> "Ok" -> "Ok" ->
>   "type=jar" -> "Apply" -> "Ok".

Then I did

> Build -> Build Artefacts -> Build.

It wrote this :

> "11:26    Compilation completed with 0 errors and 0 warnings in 10 ms"

There is no where any jar, and no error what should I do ? its been few hours I'm trying to do this, can you help me ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Okay people !
Do not use packages with dots in it.
Thats why it didn't worked I reset everything in /src/main.java and it worked have a nice day I hope I saved you people who are reading this because it happened to you ;)